# Travis-CI Complex Makefile fails

Tags: c++, makefile, travis-ci

I am new to using Travis-CI, and the C++ project that I am starting with uses a GNU Makefile, The makefile contains many functions, one of which calls other functions. I noticed that in the Travis-CI log, this function does not successfully call the other functions, instead, it leaves a blank space, which causes the build to fail. Despite it working on any computer.

The function is:

```
define Compile
mkdir -p $(@D)
if [[ $(2) == Linking ]]; then \
  $(call Print,$(2) $(@F),$(WIDTH)); \
else \
  $(call PrintCpp,$(2) $(@F),$(WIDTH)); \
fi
$(1) 2> $@.log; \
  RESULT=$$?; \
  if [ $$RESULT -ne 0 ]; then \
    $(cross); \
  else \
    $(check); \
  fi; \
  cat $@.log; \
  rm -f $@.log
endef
```

The functions called are:

```
define Line = 
$(shell printf '%0.1s' "$(2)"{1..$(1)})
endef

define Print
var="$(1)"; \
    width="$(2)";\
    printf '%s%*.*s' "$$var" 0 $$(($$width - $${#var} - 1)) "$(call 
Line,$(2),.)"
endef

define PrintCpp
var="$(1)"; \
    var=$${var%.*}.cpp; \
    width="$(2)";\
    printf '%s%*.*s' "$$var" 0 $$(($$width - $${#var} - 1)) "$(call 
Line,$(2),.)"
endef

define check =
    printf "%b\n" "$(OK_COLOR)\xE2\x9C\x94 $(NO_COLOR)"
endef

define cross =
    printf "%b\n" "$(ERR_COLOR)\xE2\x9D\x8C $(NO_COLOR)"
endef
```

The GitHub for the project can be found here:
https://github.com/LuxAtrumStudio/Pessum

And the Travis-CI log here:
https://travis-ci.org/LuxAtrumStudio/Pessum/builds/256427744

Comment: SInce your current travis builds no longer fail, I assume you solved this question?

Comment: @renemilk Sadly no. I found that the nested calling of functions was causing the error, but I found no good solution. I just settled for a less complicated makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, which turned out to be because Travis by default still uses the deprecated Ubuntu Trusty release. Trusty only has GNU Make version 3, while we require GNU Make > 4.

My problem was fixed when I switched Travis to Ubuntu Xenial by adding the following to my `.travis.yml`:

```
dist: xenial
```

Before the switch from Trusty to Xenial, `make -v` was at [GNU Make 3.81](https://travis-ci.org/bigsmoke/sapienshabitat/builds/402530615#L1114). After the switch, `make -v` is now at [GNU Make 4.1](https://travis-ci.org/bigsmoke/sapienshabitat/jobs/402548089#L995)

Switching to Xenial might require you to make some additional changes. I had to bump my Python version from 3.4 to 3.7, for example.